# MariaDB uses all /tmp space

Tags: mysql, mariadb, disk-space

I'm running a Galera cluster with MariaDB 10.

One of my nodes reports 100% usage disk for the `/tmp` table.

```
   /dev/mapper/vg0-LV--Tmp      1,8G    1,7G  228K 100% /tmp
```

I can't see files in `/tmp` with the `ls` command, but `lsof` reports:

```
mysqld     1236            mysql   14u      REG              254,5           0         17 /tmp/ibrpksHg (deleted)
mysqld     1236            mysql   15u      REG              254,5           0         19 /tmp/iboJmq1H (deleted)
mysqld     1236            mysql   16u      REG              254,5           0         20 /tmp/ibJLXol9 (deleted)
mysqld     1236            mysql   17u      REG              254,5           0         21 /tmp/ibKM4Kq5 (deleted)
mysqld     1236            mysql   21u      REG              254,5           0         22 /tmp/ibFyx8KA (deleted)
```

If I restart the node, the space is released, but the issue comes back after some time.

I don't understand what's happening here.

Any idea?

Comment: You are doing lots of large sorts (`ORDER BY`/`GROUP BY` etc ) that have to spill to disk, probably

Comment: Well it seems that there is not much activities on the server (according to show processlist). So even if this happen, the disk space should be released no ?

Answer (score 1):

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';` -- You could change that (and restart) to immediately workaround the problem.  But that is *not* a long-term solution.

Complex queries with inadequate indexes are likely to be the cause.  Set `long_query_time=1` and turn on the slowlog; wait a day; run `pt-query-digest` or `mysqldumpslow -s t` to see the 'worst' queries.  Focus on them.

If you don't see how to improve a query, post a question with `EXPLAIN SELECT...`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a tag it `[mysql] [query-optimization]`.

Answer (score 0):

i have had similar problem for a long time. what solves this without having to restart is to issue: FLUSH LOGS; this instantly frees up over 400gb of unused disk space and there is no files present.

Looks like LOGROTATE opens up the files but never closes the lock them, witch in turn just keeps growing.